# Compute Sharpe ratio and annualized Sharpe on captured bar returns or trade returns?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, log-returns, annualized

I am currently using a vectorized backtester where I have a `strategy_returns` series which is just a version of the bar-to-bar `log_returns` series where all returns that aren't between an entry/exit pair are `0`. Below is an example illustrating what I mean:

***`log_returns` Series:***
[-0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, -0.01, 0.02, -0.01, 0.02, 0.04]

***Entry/Exit Series (1 = entry, -1 = exit, 0 = none):***
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]

***`strategy_returns` Series:***
[0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, 0, 0, 0]

Would it be correct to use the captured bar-to-bar returns to compute SR and annualized SR instead of just assigning a single return value per trade?

Comment: The returns used to calculate the Sharpe Ratio are time-related (for example daily returns) they are not trade related (return on each trade). If the trading strategy has no position  during certain periods then a zero return should be assigned to those periods (days).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!